# Identify actual message language settings in R

Tags: r

I was trying to identify the language setting (the language in which messages etc. are presented) in R.

The initial situation is the following:

- I'm using Windows, so `Sys.getlocale(category="LC_MESSAGES")` is not available
- In the R console (standard editor) all messages are in German; however, `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")=""`
- In R Studio all messages are in English; `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")=""`, as well.

What I want to do is the following: Identify the *actual* R message language, i.e. the language of the messages presented to the user (German in R console, English in RStudio), and independently from the OS used. 
That means, ideally would like to avoid dealing with result strings like the ones from `Sys.getlocale()` (e.g. "de_DE.UTF-8") which depend on the OS.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "EN")` then `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")` again.

Comment: @jaySf: The problem is, I want _to find out_ what the current language is, not set it. So I get `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")=""` and this means 'English' in RStudio, and 'German' in the R console. I was wondering if there is a way to find out the actual message language currently used.

Comment: Actually you're getting `""`, and each Rstudio and R is using its defaults somehow, and particularly some*where*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. I generate errors and analyze the error messages to identify the language.

To do so, I first check for all possible language versions of the error message with the following function that returns a dataframe with the ISO country code (which I took from Wikipedia) and an error message in the respective language:

```
createmessages <- function() {
  countries <- c("AF","EG","AX","AL","DZ","AS","VI","AD","AO","AI","AQ","AG","GQ","AR","AM","AW","AC","AZ","ET","AU","BS","BH","BD","BB","BY","BE","BZ","BJ","BM","BT","BO","BQ","BA","BW","BV","BR","VG","IO","BN","BG","BF","BU","BI","EA","CL","CN","CP","CK","CR","CI","CW","DK","DD","DE","DG","DM","DO","DJ","EC","SV","ER","EE","CE","EU","FK","FO","FJ","FI","FR","FX","GF","PF","TF","GA","GM","GE","GH","GI","GD","GR","GL","GP","GU","GT","GG","GN","GW","GY","HT","HM","HN","HK","IN","ID","IM","IQ","IR","IE","IS","IL","IT","JM","JP","YE","JE","JO","YU","KY","KH","CM","CA","IC","CV","KZ","QA","KE","KG","KI","CC","CO","KM","CD","CG","KP","KR","XK","HR","CU","KW","LA","LS","LV","LB","LR","LY","LI","LT","LU","MO","MG","MW","MY","MV","ML","MT","MA","MH","MQ","MR","MU","YT","MK","MX","FM","MD","MC","MN","ME","MS","MZ","MM","NA","NR","NP","NC","NZ","NT","NI","NL","AN","NE","NG","NU","MP","NF","NO","OM","AT","TL","PK","PS","PW","PA","PG","PY","PE","PH","PN","PL","PT","PR","RE","RW","RO","RU","SB","BL","MF","ZM","WS","SM","ST","SA","SE","CH","SN","RS","CS","SC","SL","ZW","SG","SX","SK","SI","SO","ES","LK","SH","KN","LC","PM","VC","ZA","SD","GS","SS","SR","SJ","SZ","SY","TJ","TW","TZ","TH","TG","TK","TO","TT","TA","TD","CZ","CS","TN","TR","TM","TC","TV","SU","UG","UA","HU","UM","UY","UZ","VU","VA","VE","AE","US","UK","VN","WF","CX","EH","ZR","CF","CY")
  e <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(countries))
  {
    Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"=countries[i])
    res <- tryCatch( { xhajakjkula/1 }, error = function(err) { return(err) })
    e[i] <- res$message
  }
  Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="DE")
  return(data.frame(countries,e))
}
```

After analyzing the resulting data frame I found that only six of the ISO country codes yield error message in a language different from English (namely  Polish, French, Spanish, German, Turkish and Italian). I use the error message to create a function that returns the language (with English as the default return value:

```
getlanguage <- function() {
  res <- tryCatch( { xhajakjkula/1 }, error = function(err) { return(err) })
  lang <- "EN"
  if(res$message == "Objekt 'xhajakjkula' nicht gefunden") lang <- "DE"
  if(res$message == "objet 'xhajakjkula' introuvable") lang <- "FR"
  if(res$message == "oggetto \"xhajakjkula\" non trovato") lang <- "IT"
  if(res$message == "nie znaleziono obiektu 'xhajakjkula'") lang <- "PL"
  if(res$message == "objeto 'xhajakjkula' no encontrado") lang <- "ES"
  if(res$message == "'xhajakjkula' nesnesi bulunamadi") lang <- "TR"
  return(lang)
}
```

Comment: Good approach! Please note: I have tested your `createmessages` function with R3.4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 but it always uses the language set at startup-time of R and the language cannot be changed during R run-time.

Comment: A slight modification of this approach (thanks to Uwe Ligges) is to use something like this: tryCatch( { "abc"/1 }, error = function(err) { return(err) }) to produce the error. When you develop R packages, this code will not fail to pass CRAN's automatic checks, while my original approach above (accessing a non-existing object) produces a validation error.